# Infinite sign switching 1/prime series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Given the following series

\begin{equation}
\sum _{p{\text{ prime}} \atop p{\text{ is the i'th prime}}}{ \frac {(-1)^i}{p}}
\end{equation}

(sry maybe there is a better way to describe this series)  so the first n steps would look like this:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{11} - ...
\end{equation}

My Questions:

1. Does this series converge? It seems to me that it should but i would like to see a proof.

Here is what the first 500 steps look like plotted:
[image]

2. The number it seems to converges to (gained from a simulation) is round about 0.2696... Is there anything special about this number? Does it have some name?
3. What is the exact number this series converges to (if it does), and if this is possible to say is this number irrational (I would guess yes)?

Comment: It converges by the alternating series test.

Comment: [This OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A078437) has the value.

Comment: There is no generating function for those kind of series thus no hope to find a closed-form or say anything about (ir)rationality of the limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It converges by the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).  The terms alternate in sign and decrease monotonically in magnitude.  The number is almost certainly irrational, as most numbers are, but I suspect a proof is difficult.